# Silverlight 4 RichTextBox Bind Data using DataContext

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, richtextbox

I am working with Silverlight 4 and trying to put my test apps multilingual but I am having some trouble when I arrive to the "RichTextBox" control. I am able to bind it properly by doing back-code (c#), but when trying using the "DataContext" attributes I am not able to load it at all.

I have created a FormatConverter that return a Block (paragraph) for testing and my code where I have my RichTextBox looks like:

```
   <RichTextBox x:Name="rtaTest" BorderThickness="0" IsReadOnly="True" UseLayoutRounding="True" 
DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource Localization}, Path=Home.MainContent, Converter={StaticResource ParagraphFormatConverter}}">
    </RichTextBox>
```

I am wondering if there is a way of binding a RichTextBox from the XAML.

Comment: I'm not quite seeing what you goal is to assign to the DataContext

Comment: It is because I want to put in my rich text area different localization (french/english/etc.) but I want to bind my blocks when I load the page. Sorry if i'm not clear... my english is not my first language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may be a little confused about the used of the DataContext.  You might for example have some Rich text where some children of one or more `InlineUIContainer` elements may retrieve their text from a property of some object.  You would assign the object to the `DataContext`.

Whilst I'm not quite sure what you were expecting to achieve but I suspect that what you really need is for your converter to actually return a `BlocksCollection` (even if it just contains the single `Block` you were originaly returning) and then to bind as:-

```
<RichTextArea x:Name="rtaTest" BorderThickness="0" IsReadOnly="True"
 UseLayoutRounding="True"
 Blocks="{Binding Source={StaticResource Localization},
   Path=Home.MainContent, Converter={StaticResource ParagraphFormatConverter}}" />
```

Answer (score 5):

**Run** seems to support databinding in SL4, as in:

```
<RichTextBox>
  <Paragraph>
    <Run Text="{Binding Path=LineFormatted}" />
  </Paragraph>
</RichTextBox>
```

Answer (score 1):

This FillFromXml is a WPF thing? Don't see it in Silverlight.

Answer (score 0):

Blocks cannot be set, they can only be fetched. One way to set the blocks for a `RichTextArea` is

```
public static void UpdateRichTextArea(RichTextArea area, string xmlText)
{
    if (area == null)
    return;

    area.Blocks.FillFromXml(xmlText, true);
}
```