# Bind the text of RichTextBox from Xaml

Tags: c#, silverlight, silverlight-4.0, richtextbox

How to Bind the text of  RichTextArea from xaml

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no built in way to do that. You can create Text attached property and bind to it like discussed [here](http://marlongrech.wordpress.com/2009/03/25/richtextbox-text-property-where-are-you-hiding/)

Comment: The link provided is specific to WPF.  The RichTextBox in Silverlight doesn't have a Document property on it.

Comment: I'd like to second Steve's comment.

Answer (score 26):

They've got the easier answer here:

[Silverlight 4 RichTextBox Bind Data using DataContext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2267586/silverlight-4-richtextbox-bind-data-using-datacontext)
and it works like a charm.

```
<RichTextBox>
  <Paragraph>
    <Run Text="{Binding Path=LineFormatted}" />
  </Paragraph>
</RichTextBox>
```

Comment: This also works great in Windows 8/8.1 XAML. Thanks!!

Comment: Simple but effective solution, Brilliant

Comment: As @dex3703 was saying, this works in WPF with the syntax:    `<RichTextBox>
                                                <FlowDocument>
                                                    <Paragraph>
                                                        <Run Text="{Binding Path=MyText}" />
                                                    </Paragraph>
                                                </FlowDocument>
                                            </RichTextBox>`

Comment: Just an FYI for others.. this will fail if the user does a SelectAll and Delete since that paragraph element will be removed.

Answer (score 4):

Here is the solution I came up with.  I created a custom RichTextViewer class and inherited from RichTextBox.

```
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Markup;
using System.Windows.Media;

namespace System.Windows.Controls
{
    public class RichTextViewer : RichTextBox
    {
        public const string RichTextPropertyName = "RichText";

        public static readonly DependencyProperty RichTextProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register(RichTextPropertyName,
                                        typeof (string),
                                        typeof (RichTextBox),
                                        new PropertyMetadata(
                                            new PropertyChangedCallback
                                                (RichTextPropertyChanged)));

        public RichTextViewer()
        {
            IsReadOnly = true;
            Background = new SolidColorBrush {Opacity = 0};
            BorderThickness = new Thickness(0);
        }

        public string RichText
        {
            get { return (string) GetValue(RichTextProperty); }
            set { SetValue(RichTextProperty, value); }
        }

        private static void RichTextPropertyChanged(DependencyObject dependencyObject, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs dependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs)
        {
            ((RichTextBox) dependencyObject).Blocks.Add(
                XamlReader.Load((string) dependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs.NewValue) as Paragraph);

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [`InlineUIContainer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.documents.inlineuicontainer.Aspx) class if you want to bind a XAML control inside of an inline typed control

```
<RichTextBlock>
<Paragraph>
    <InlineUIContainer>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name"} />
    </InlineUIContainer>
</Paragraph>
</RichTextBlock>
```

Answer (score 0):

This can't be done, you have to manually update it. Document is not a DependencyProperty.