# Setting text in a RichTextBox

Tags: c#, wpf, richtextbox

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [RichTextBox (WPF) does not have string property “Text”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/957441/richtextbox-wpf-does-not-have-string-property-text)

This is ridiculous, my RichTextBox has no document or paragraph property.
How am I supposed to add text to it via C#?

```
<ScrollViewer Margin="16,56,16,16">
                <RichTextBox x:Name="PREVIEWTEMP"
                             HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
                             VerticalContentAlignment="Top"
                             Padding="0,6,0,0"
                             Height="528"
                             Width="400"
                             IsReadOnly="True">
                    <Paragraph>
                        <Run Text="RichTextBox" />
                    </Paragraph>
                </RichTextBox>
            </ScrollViewer>
```

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/957441/richtextbox-wpf-does-not-have-string-property-text

Comment: you might also want to take a look here regarding document and paragraph, though it does not exactly answer your question: http://go4answers.webhost4life.com/Example/tabcontrol-scrollviewer-richtextbox-192242.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Paragraph needs to sit inside a  element.

Take a look at this site, it has some good examples http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/wpf-richtextbox/

Comment: Creating FlowDocuments is not possible in the WP7 SDK.

Comment: Would help if you specified you were using WP7. Without that tag you're code looks like WPF.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a RichTextViewer which inherits from RichTextBox as showed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2361219/bind-the-text-of-richtextbox-from-xaml) (post by e-rock).